# (Android) Views array simple form validator

Tags: android, forms, validation

I wrote this simple form validator to see if an EditText field is empty or not. I'm calling this method from a fragment, but it always seems to pass the if statement even while it's empty. Here's my code:

```
 private boolean checkForm() {
                boolean returnValue = false;
                View[] view1;
                view1 = new View[] {(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name),
                        (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.companyname),
                        (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.email),
                        (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.website),
                        (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.other),
                        (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.whichelements)
                };
                for(View item : view1)
                {
                    if(item.toString().trim().length() > 0){
                        returnValue = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        returnValue = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return returnValue;
            }
```

When I debug it also says the string is empty which you can see here at the mTransformed: http://gyazo.com/cfd58bc075b5cfbf01c0bce5f8702a15

Why is the condition always true, even when the string is not empty? String.Equals() also doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because `item.toString()` is not returning the content of the `EditText`

```
 for(View item : view1) {
     if (TextUtils.isEmpty(((TextView)view).getText().toString())) {
        return false;
     } 
 }
 return true;
```

Comment: You're amazing! That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

I think because this boolean variable based on the last View.
and you need getTex() method to get text inside EditText

Comment: Actually, there is nothing wrong with the boolean. The for loop breaks when an invalid EditText is found, and the whole block returns true only if all EditTexts were valid. (Though if the array was empty, that would still result in a false result. That doesn't feel right.)